# Reverse of "hyphenated [nationality]"

Tags: single-word-requests

If I want to talk about Irish-Americans, Polish-Americans, and all other [nationality]-Americans, where the country of origin differs but the country they live in is the same, I can use the term "hyphenated American".

But if I want to talk about, say, Polish-Americans, Polish-Australians, Polish-Englishmen, and all other Polish-[nationality], where the country of origin stays the same but the country they live in differs, what term can I use? Polish hyphenateds? Polish hyphenators? Members of the Polish diaspora?

For example:

> Polish-hyphenateds have different views on international relations than Polish people themselves.

Comment: Following the same logic as *hyphenated American*, you get ***hyphenated Pole***, a term which is very rare but does exist.

Comment: @J.Siebeneichler Please use the **Your Answer** box when providing answers.

Comment: @J.Siebeneichler I've edited my question. Do you understand it properly now?

Comment: You have accepted an answer that advises users to use the term overseas Polish. Of course, in English Polish is not used as a mass noun for Polish people, and so anyone coming here for expert advice may find themselves unwittingly producing gibberish in their important document or assignment. Would you mind considering unselecting that answer, please?  Tommy's answer looks impeccable to me ...

Comment: @Araucaria expatriates wouldn't apply for Polish immigrants to other countries.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I am probably missing something, but why wouldn't it?

Comment: @Araucaria expatriates is a slightly nuanced word, which suggests the person isn't going to permanently live there.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Hmm, yes, that's true. Anyhow, the currently selected answer is positively dangerous for readers here! Perhaps *emigre* is better than *expatriate*.

Comment: Here is [a complete list of all the occurrences of "overseas Polish"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Overseas+Polish%22&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGhLiuia3QAhWHAcAKHThjA9YQ_AUIDSgG&biw=1366&bih=662) from printed books from Googlebooks. Notice that there is not one instance of *verseas Polish* being used as a noun phrase to denote Polish people overseas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Polish nationals abroad (overseas) or Overseas Polish* is the right term to use. For example:

Guidance: [Support for British nationals abroad](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/support-for-british-nationals-abroad-a-guide).

[www.gov.uk]

The word [diaspora](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/support-for-british-nationals-abroad-a-guide) is sometimes used, too which means:

> People who have spread or been dispersed from their homeland.

Example: [American diaspora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_diaspora)

> The American diaspora or overseas Americans refers to the population
>   of United States citizens who relocate, temporarily or permanently, to
>   foreign countries.

[Oxford Online Dictionary, Wikipedia]

Comment: 'Polish Overseas' wouldn't cover the Polish-hyphenates in the very many countries which are not separated from Poland by water. There are relatively few countries for which 'overseas' can be used accurately as a synonym for 'abroad'.

Answer (score 2):

"Polish [Expatriates](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expatriate#Noun)", perhaps?